# Связь разных форм

Tags: qt

Есть 2 формы, на MainWindow 2 кнопки. Одна вызывает новое окно. В новом окне тоже есть кнопка. Как при нажатии на кнопку во второй форме передать название этой кнопки во вторую кнопку на первой форме?
Объяснение в скрине: [ссылка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4IJr.jpg)

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "test.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    tests = new test();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    tests->show();
    hide();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "test.h"
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    test *tests;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
#include "ui_test.h"

test::test(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::test)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

test::~test()
{
    delete ui;
}

void test::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    close();
}
```

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class test;
}

class test : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit test(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~test();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::test *ui;
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определи в классе окна сигнал и посылай его при нажатии кнопки:

**test.h**

```
class test : public QWidget
{
...

signals:
   void sendTextFromButton(QString); // сигнал

private slots:
   void on_pushButton_clicked();
...
};
```

**test.cpp**

```
void test::on_pushButton_clicked() {
   emit sendTextFromButton(ui->mybutton->text()); // отправляем сигнал по нажатию кнопки
   close();
}
```

Создай слот в главном окне, куда будет приходит сигнал:

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
...
private slots:
   void onSendTextFromButton(QString text);
...
};
```

Пропиши коннект сигнал-слот:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    tests = new test();
    connect(tests, &test::sendTextFromButton, this, &MainWindow::onSendTextFromButton);

}

void MainWindow::onSendTextFromButton(QString text) {
   ui->mybutton->setText(text);
}
```

Так же можно почитать про [сигналы и слоты](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: [кнопка не передает значения в другую кнопку(](https://prnt.sc/122000o)

Comment: @Mkorny вы должны сами это значение забрать из одной кнопки и поставить в другую/ см.QPushButton::text(), QPushButton::setText().

Comment: как обращаться к кнопкам в заголовочном файле?..

Comment: По имени. ui->mybutton->text();

Comment: В том то и дело, что так не получается...

Comment: @Mkorny какую ошибку выводит? В примере, вместо "mybutton" подставь objectName своей кнопки.

Comment: [вот](https://prnt.sc/1231x3z)

Comment: Вынеси определение функции onSendTextFromButton() в cpp-файл

Comment: Исправил пример.

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо большое..

Comment: Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы эта кнопка меняла название кнопки, которая вызвала это окно? То бишь, у меня есть проект Судоку, где я создал через кнопки поле. При нажатии на кнопку вызывается окно с цифрами от 1 до 9, при нажатии которой эта цифра передала название кнопке, которая вызвала это окно.. [скрин](https://prnt.sc/123bmj9)

Comment: Можно перед показом окна, передавать в него указатель на кнопку, и уже в окне менять текст кнопки по указателю. Тогда не нужен сигнал sendTextFromButton. Только создай у окна метод, например, setButton(QPushButton* b) { _button = b; }, и собственно сам указатель объяви в классе окна: QPushButton* _button;

Comment: [Архив с программой](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/YBndiQbr5NsAnA) Пытаюсь сделать реализацию такую, как вы показали первый раз, от кнопки к кнопке, но не получается. Просто не передает.. Кидаю всю папку, потому что не хочу загромождать комментарии. Реализацию передачи с формы в форму в классах Form и numbers. Наведите, если не сложно, на мою ошибку, спасибо

Comment: Оно и не будет работать, когда numbers::setButton() у тебя приватный метод. Заводишь слот на каждую кнопку в классе form. И в каждом пишешь, например для кнопки 81: { numbs.setButton(ui->btn81); numbs.show(); }. В классе numbers тоже заводишь слот на каждую кнопку и пишешь: { _button->setText(ui->btn1->text()); close(); }.

Comment: И numbers::setButton() сделай public, а QPushButton* _button; наоборот в приват.

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо, и прошу прощения за свою глупость..